# Hide a menu-item and its submenus and display a 'Log in' link if the user is logged out

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, menus, woocommerce-offtopic

I need, somehow, to enable that when you logout, that *'My Account'* item is getting hidden from the navbar, and instead it displays a *'Log in'* link. The item *'My Account'* also have submenus with the items *'Log out'* and *'Track your order'*. This should be hidden as well *(I guess it gets hidden when you hide the parent 'My Account')*.

I use the theme Mystile, WordPress and I use the latest version of WooCommerce.

Any suggestions how to?

The JSFiddle of my menu's HTML source: http://jsfiddle.net/qcuckt1f/

```
<nav id="navigation" class="col-full parent" role="navigation">
    <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fr parent">
        <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-home menu-item-68"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/">Forside</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-67" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-67"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/butik/">Butik</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-61"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/support/">Kundeservice</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-62" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-8 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-62 parent"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/min-konto/">Min Konto</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/min-konto/track-din-ordre/">Track din ordre</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="http://renhud.square-brain.com/min-konto/log-ud/">Log Ud</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using `wp_nav_menu()`? Can you provide its arguments and the HTML source of your navbar?

Comment: I use a custom menu, created via the custom menu option in wordpress. I'll post the menu HTML, give me a minute.

Comment: I'll answer it tomorrow if there's still no valid answer. I also need the PHP code of your navbar.

Comment: I posted html in a jsfiddle (link in post).

Comment: @5ervant there is a lot of php files, so which do you need? just the index.php and the section with nav?

Comment: How about its server-side code in a PHP file? You need to find it!

Comment: @5ervant hmm. Functions php is the theme php functions... I'll keep searching. Hang on!

Comment: Maybe it's on *'sidebar.php'*, *'header.php'* or else..

Comment: Can't seems to find it, i'll keep looking.

Comment: @5ervant i'll start xhecking the admin files.

Comment: Are you searching on the core *"wp-admin"* files? No, it's not in there, go to the *"\wp-content\themes\your-theme-domain"* and look for a *"wp_nav_menu("*.

Comment: I just found a solution a few minutes ago. Creating a logged in menu and a logged out menu. And then switch regarding the users login state. I really Appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the OP have managed to solve his/her problem by doing this, which can be found at [Different menus for logged-in users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Different_menus_for_logged-in_users).

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) );
} else {
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-out-menu' ) );
}
```

The more shorter way to achieve that is by doing this, which is [posted in new developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#div-comment-208) version:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => is_user_logged_in() ? 'logged-in-menu' : 'logged-out-menu'
) );
```

The robust way to achieve that without creating two different menus, is to use a custom `'walker'` function:

1. Look for the custom walker class that your theme is using in its `wp_nav_menu()`:

   ```
   wp_nav_menu( array(
       // More arguments here..
       'walker'         => new Your_Theme_Custom_Nav_Walker(),
   ) );
   ```
2. Write a new class in your *"functions.php"*, extend `Your_Theme_Custom_Nav_Walker` class *(you can easily search its declaration by using an IDE)* or extend the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class if they're not using any custom walker, and copy the necessary function*(s)* to modify, mostly the `start_el()` function, of that walker class in their declaration. Here is the simple custom class that extends the `Walker_Nav_Menu` that I build to suit your needs:

   ```
   class WP_Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

   /**
    * Start the element output.
    *
    * @see Walker::start_el()
    *
    * @since 3.0.0
    *
    * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
    * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
    * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
    * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
    * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
    */
   public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
       $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

       /**
        * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
        *
        * @since 3.0.0
        * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
        *
        * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
        * @param object $item    The current menu item.
        * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
        * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
        */
       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
       $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

       /**
        * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
        *
        * @since 3.0.1
        * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
        *
        * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
        * @param object $item    The current menu item.
        * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
        * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
        */
       $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
       $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';


       // MODIFICATION STARTS HERE!!
       $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names;

       if (apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) === 'My Account') {
           if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
               $output .= '>';
           } else {
               $output .= '><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/wp-login.php">Log in</a></li>';
               $output .= '<li style="display: none">';
           }
       } else {
           $output .= '>';
       }
       // MODIFICATION ENDS HERE!!


       $atts = array();
       $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
       $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
       $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
       $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

       /**
        * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
        *
        * @since 3.6.0
        * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
        *
        * @param array $atts {
        *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
        *
        *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
        *     @type string $target Target attribute.
        *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
        *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
        * }
        * @param object $item  The current menu item.
        * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
        * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
        */
       $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

       $attributes = '';
       foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
           if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
               $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
               $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
           }
       }

       $item_output = $args->before;
       $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
       /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
       $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
       $item_output .= '</a>';
       $item_output .= $args->after;

       /**
        * Filter a menu item's starting output.
        *
        * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
        * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
        * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
        *
        * @since 3.0.0
        *
        * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
        * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
        * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
        * @param array  $args        An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
        */
       $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
   }

   }
   ```
3. You can use that `WP_Custom_Nav_Walker` like this:

   ```
   wp_nav_menu( array(
       // More arguments here..
       'walker'         => new WP_Custom_Nav_Walker(),
   ) );
   ```

You can check [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/196901/73330) for another example how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WordPress function `is_user_logged_in()` to check that, and create some basic if statements to show and hide the appropriate code.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. Could you give me an example on the if statements write? Keep in mind that i need the submenus to be created too!:)